# What’s the best practice for storing prompts when using them in code , git or database?

Tags: recommendation, code

I’ve been asked at work for best practices, and I have a strong sense and also saw examples, but would like to hear from other users,

Guiding questions:
Git or Database?
What’s working best for you and why?

Ultimately the real question is:
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and what worked best for me, storing the prompts in markdown files in git was best, inside the project.

So I have a prompts folder, in it each usecase, and in it relevant prompts in structure:

```
usecase.system.md
usecase.user.md
usecase.assistant.md
```

Edit following @Mentalist comment question:
I found this helpful because:

- I can change code and prompt together and they always fit.
- Easier to read. When someone else, or my future self, reads the code, it’s easier to understand what’s going on.
- Version history. Something broke? Revert is easy.
- You did nothing and something broke? Checking the db is always a bit harder, especially if you have prod env. Maybe it was the model that changed?

About this specific structure where all prompts reside in one place, split by purpose (folders) and each has its own role.

- Markdown. I can parse the markdown and read it better (headers, bullets, etc.)
- Findable. Since they are not classes, I have to find them by name.
- Loadable. I have a wrapper class that loads them by name. I just type the name of the assistant I need.
- Prompts sit close together. Easy to duplicate the adjust to your need, compare styles and make mass changes.
- Findable 2. Easy to know at a glance which assistants you already have in code and avoid duplication when code becomes complex.

Note: Here is a simple code example in Python
https://github.com/OriNachum/tau/blob/main/services/prompt_service.py
In other code I added the ability to inject dynamic content as well.

Comment: "What’s working best for you and why?" Thanks for sharing what worked for you. But... **why** did you find this approach to be the best?